# How to send javascript variable data to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to send a javascript variable which contains an image base64 (png) value (Too big for GET requests). How do i send this base64 value to the php page (POST request) so as to decode base64 and then save it.

```
var base64 = this.tobase64(); // store base64 value to this variable

        $.post('/js/uploadify/handler.php', {basevalue: base64});

                });

    window.location = "http://localhost/file/handler.php";
```

I tried the above code but it does not work,

I want to send the value with an onclick event on a button (which is not a submit button). I am not using forms.

**PHP CODE**

```
$val = $_POST['basevalue'];
echo $val;
```

I get      Notice: Undefined index: basevalue error

thanks!.

Comment: Post the php code as well.

Comment: The `window.location` is probably wrecking the POST.

Comment: check edit added php code

Comment: is the php code in `effectsuploadify.php` or `handler.php`

Comment: $val = file_get_contents( php://input );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for a success on `$.post()`.

```
function wl(){
 window.location = "http://localhost/file/handler.php";
}
var base64 = this.tobase64(); // store base64 value to this variable
$.post('/js/uploadify/effectsuploadify.php',{
  basevalue: base64,
  success: wl,
});
```

Comment: Did you remove `window.location = "http://localhost/file/handler.php";` from after the script?

Comment: ok. I removed that. now it does not redirect how do i fix this.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I used the wrong method (tobase64)..Thanks alot..

Comment: oops! still getting the same error even after giving correct method name nothing in console. page redirects with undefines index error.

Comment: The problem must be with your PHP. The post was successful.

Comment: do I need php5 ?, How do i check my php version. I am using xampp.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27593/discussion-between-mooseman-and-user1910290)

Answer (score 0):

POST only sends the value of form's feilds to next page.
In order to send your image to next page, assign it to value of hidden feild and submit form using java script.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
form.setAttribute("action", "http://localhost/file/handler.php");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "image");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", base64);

form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```